# Modify object inside array without using loop

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in javascript which can modify array value. I have done it by using `for loop` and there is another method call `forEach`. I wanted to get it done by using only one line. Like I have seen code for converting onject into array by using `Array.prototype.slice`. So can we get the requirement done by using similar function. I google it but did not find any relevant post.

```
this.gome = (function(data){
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          data[i].id = i
        }
        return data })(data.gome);

this.gome = Array.prototype.slice.call(data.gome,//code) // something like that.
```

Comment: What's wrong with `forEach` exactly? Should be perfect here.

Comment: by using slice are you going to only need part of the array

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is your friend:

```
this.gome = data.gome.map((x, i) => ({...x, id: i}));
```

Or without ES2016 :

```
this.gome = data.gome.map((x, i) => Object.assign({}, x, {id: i }));
```

Answer (score 0):

this will add the values with one line, it's still a for loop though

```
for(var i = 0, l = data.length; i<l; i++){ data[i].id = i };
```